# How do I correct this error?

Tags: html, css

When I hover an item in a list and the list text contains a linebreak, the hover effect seems to be inconsistent.

```
<ul id="nav1" class="greenbullet">
    <li>
        <a href="" class="tsize">Surdite : en Europe, 40 <br />millions de personnes sont concernees</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" class="tsize">GuideCaro, une entreprise pionniere, partenaire de Garnier</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" class="tsize">Garnier renforce son accessibilite en lancant le service Sourdline </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The css

```
#nav1 { list-style:url(../../img/02-tri-SDB-light/images/greenbullet.png) }

#nav1 li a { text-decoration:none;color:#019b99 }

#nav1 li { margin-left:40px }

#nav1 li:hover, #nav1 li:hover a { list-style:url(../../img/02-    tri-SDB-light/images/puce2.png); color:#FFF;background-color:#019b99; }
```

How do I sort this out?

Comment: Your question is a little too vague. What is it doing that's "inconsistent"? If you could provide a demo page, that would help tremendously.

Comment: Create an example at http://jsfiddle.net/ which shows the problem.

Comment: I looked at this, but can't find any inconsistency, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a fiddle and can't see the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/V654e/

However, we can't see your `list-style` because they are images.  So the problem may be there, specifically with the `:hover` style.  There appears to be a break in the `url` after the `02`?

`#nav1 li:hover, #nav1 li:hover a { list-style:url(../../img/02-    tri-SDB-light/images/puce2.png); color:#FFF;background-color:#019b99; }`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `#nav1 li a:hover`, or simpler `#nav1 a:hover`. Otherwise, the hover won't work on IE6.